# The IDynamicPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not implemented by this provider

Tags: registry

I m trying to add a registry entry but i get the following error :

New-ItemProperty : Cannot use interface. The IDynamicPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not implemented by this provider

> ## Disable IE first pop up
>
> $registryPath =
> "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"
>
> $Name = "DisableFirstRunCustomize"
>
> $value = "00000001"
>
> New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
>
> New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value `
> -PropertyType DWORD

Answer (score 3):

Your `$registryPath` is incorrect. Correct syntax is :

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"
```

See [Update or Add Registry Key Value with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/)

Comment: See https://community.spiceworks.com/t/cannot-user-interface-error/711156/4 for other supported formats like `HKCU`